# How to limit photo viewer to only display image files in the array?

Tags: vb.net

## array of the picture

```
Dim PicsBMP As New List(Of PictureBox)

For i As Integer = 0 To similarImageNewList.Count - 1    
    Pics.Add(New PictureBox)
    Pics(i).Tag = i
    Pics(i).Image = Image.FromFile(similarImageNewList(i))
    Pics(i).Top = 25
    Pics(i).Left = (i * 250) + 20
    Pics(i).Width = 200
    Pics(i).Height = 200
    Pics(i).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    Pics(i).SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

    AddHandler Pics(i).MouseClick, AddressOf imageCapture_mouseDoubleClick

    Panel1.Controls.Add(Pics(i))    
Next
```

## mousedoubleClick

```
Private Sub imageCapture_mouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim Pics As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    Dim selected As Integer = DirectCast(Pics.Tag, Integer)
    Dim filename As String = similarImageNewList(selected)

    Try
        Process.Start(filename)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error opening image file.",
                        "Load Watch Image Error",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
                        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
    End Try
End Sub
```

## array of the selected picture

```
Dim imagePathName As String = imageName(count).Substring(0, imageName(count).Length - 6)
Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(getDirectory, imagePathName + "*.jpg")

Dim fileName As String

For Each fileName In fileEntries
    If (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName)) Then
        similarImageNewList.Add(fileName)
    End If
Next
```

When the `Process.Start(filename)` is triggered, the windows photo viewer will be displaying all of the file images in the file.. I only want the photo viewer to be displaying the photos included in the `similarImageNewList`.(i) loop..

Comment: Please don't submit a question when you can see that the code is barley readable.  Also, if you have additional information that is relevant to the question, add it to the question, rather than posting a comment.  You ought to only be posting a comment in direct response to someone else and, even then, something that is relevant to everyone regarding the question ought to be added to the question.

Comment: You're the one calling `Process.Start`.  It's not going to display anything that you don't tell it to.  If `filename` is for a file you don't want to display, don;t call `Process.Start`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney fileName is the one which i want to display at Process.start. For this, the default programme popped will be windows photo viewer. The photo viewer has the function to navigate left and right through the other photos, of which what i want to display in the set is the array which populates similarImageNewList..

Comment: @jmcilhinney lets say the similarImageNewList gets me an array result of
basketball.jpg
basketball-1.jpg
basketball-2.jpg
basketball-3.jpg

in the photo viewer on windows 7 i only want the user to be able to navigate left and right only with these 4 files. Because what i'm getting now is that after user triggers the right button to see the next photo from basketball-3.jpg, he will be also able to view another photo soccer.jpg

Comment: @jmcilhinney there are also other file name, but my function searches on the textbox which user keys and includes a  Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(getDirectory, imagePathName + "*.jpg")

Comment: Why don't you show the Image in your app, without the System's Image Viewer? (btw, in my machines, for example, if you *start* a `JPEG` file, you open PhotoShop).

Comment: @jimi they would want it to be displayed on windows photo viewer as you can navigate left and right and the program is simple the way it is as to not let people have too much edits on the image

Comment: Adding two buttons to *navigate* the list of images you have is not really that hard :) Maybe you could ask a question about this instead. It would simplify the whole thing.

Comment: @jimi sorry, when Dim PicsBMP As New List(Of PictureBox), it produces picturebox on the panel. What i''m missing out is that when i double click on the picture box, thats where the problem comes..

Comment: When you call `Process.Start`, all you're doing is sending Windows a commandline and it is up to the OS what it does with it.  If you simply send the path of a data file, e.g. an image, Windows will open the default application for the file type and pass it the path as an argument.  It's then up to the app what it does with that path.  That is all outside of your control.  On systems with other default apps for viewing images, it wouldn't even open the Photos app.  All you could do is specify the app to open and pass commandline arguments to specify behaviour, but Photos doesn't support that.

Comment: I guess you could copy all the image files in your list into a temp folder and then provide a path from there.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i thought that there will be a way to display what is in the loop..

Comment: Then you thought wrong.  Like I said, you're just telling the OS to display an image in the default app.  What the default app then chooses to do is outside your control.  If the default app is built to display all apps in the same folder then that's what will happen.  If you want images displayed a particular way, do it yourself.

Comment: @jmcilhinney however i do not have access over the file so..

Comment: @jmcilhinney but what i do have is the image file directory..

Comment: Gee, if only I'd already suggested copying just the files you wanted to expose into a different folder.

Comment: @jmcilhinney now i get it.. but can you shed some light on how to copy the image into a temporary folder..